# uploading the html file produced from gnuplot canvas

Tags: html, canvas, gnuplot

I made a html file using gnuplot canvas:

```
gnuplot> set terminal canvas
Terminal type set to 'canvas'
Options are ' solid butt size 600,400 fsize 10 lw 1 fontscale 1 standalone'
gnuplot> set output 'output.html'  
gnuplot> plot [0:25] sin(x)
```

But when I opened the output.html at browser, it didn't display anything, just blank page.
I looked the content of output.html, it seems ok.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: This works fine for me. Check you are using the address
`file:///path/to/my/file/output.html`
Check also that your browser is up to date and the file permissions are making the file readable.

Answer (score 1):

Please check output.html : gnuplot will automatically generate such lines as :

```
<script src="C:/yourpath/canvastext.js"></script>
<script src="C:/yourpath/gnuplot_common.js"></script>
...
```

While Google Chrome will read these without any problem, Firefox will not load, unless you change the lines to :

```
<script src="file://C:/yourpath/canvastext.js"></script>
<script src="file://C:/yourpath/gnuplot_common.js"></script>
...
```

Which hopefully should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clue - exactly helped me ( since I was running gnuplot in cygwin )
and chrome didn't know where to look